# How to call a method

Tags: objective-c, method-call

I have a method with the signature `- (void)addStringsToArray`. I want to call it in the `viewDidLoad` method. How do I call it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Method calls (or, actually, message sends) in Objective-C have the syntax `[receiver selector]`.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
  // Where MyClass is the class your method is in.
  MyClass *object = [[MyClass alloc] init];
  [object addStringsToArray];
}
```

Here, `object` is the receiver, and `addStringsToArray` is the selector. Use `self` as the receiver if your method is in the same class as the current method (i.e. your view controller).

I highly recommend you to read [The Objective-C Programming Language](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Introduction/introObjectiveC.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163). The answer to your question is under "Object Messaging" in the first chapter.

Answer (score 1):

I'm presuming that your confusion is because the method you want to call is inside the same UIViewController class. In that specific case, you're looking for 'self'.

[self addStringsToArray];

Answer (score 0):

If you have wrote this method in same implementation file of your ViewController earlier:

[self addStringsToArray];